# MySQL - how to GROUP BY the result of another query?

Tags: sql, mysql, subquery

I have a visit table (visit_table), structure:

- ID
- IP_address
- timestamp

and a table (country_table) with country names for IP ranges

- ID
- begin_IP (start of IP range)
- end_IP (end of IP range)
- begin_num (the numerical equivalent of begin_IP, i.e. INET_ATON(begin_IP))
- end_num
- country_code (e.g. US)
- country_name
  (based on http://www.maxmind.com/app/csv )

I'm using MySQL 5.0.67 and would like to write a query to return the number of visits by country, so something along the lines of:

```
  SELECT country.table.country_name, 
         count(distinct visit_table.IP_address)  
    FROM country_table, visit_table  
   WHERE country_name = (SELECT country_name  
                           FROM country_table  
                          WHERE INET_ATON(visits.IP_address) >= begin_num  
                            AND INET_ATON( visits.IP_Address) <= end_num  
                          LIMIT 0,1 )  
GROUP BY country_table.country_name
```

I'm pretty sure I'm doing something wrong but don't know how to fix - some sort of JOIN or doing something with the SELECT or GROUP BY statement?  Any pointers welcome!

Comment: I think you can write a select statement in the group by clause in the form of a subselect. That works on Oracle, maybe it works on mysql, too. Can someone confirm this?

Answer (score 3):

Use:

```
  SELECT c.country_name, 
         COUNT(DISTINCT v.IP_address)  
    FROM COUNTRY_TABLE c
    JOIN VISIT_TABLE v ON v.country_name = c.country_name
   WHERE INET_ATON(v.IP_Address) BETWEEN begin_num AND end_num  
GROUP BY c.country_name
```

If there's no country for that IP range, you won't get anything.  But if there's more than one country returned from the range, the query needs to be updated to handle it.

If you want a country that might not have ip addresses captured for it, use:

```
   SELECT c.country_name, 
          COUNT(DISTINCT v.IP_address)  
     FROM COUNTRY_TABLE c
LEFT JOIN VISIT_TABLE v ON v.country_name = c.country_name
    WHERE INET_ATON(v.IP_Address) BETWEEN begin_num AND end_num  
 GROUP BY c.country_name
```

Comment: @Pentium10: Grouping or JOINing by the data type that uses less bytes to store the value should perform better.  An index might be considered, but will negatively impact INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE queries...

Answer (score 1):

Yes you want a join:

```
SELECT country_table.country_name, count(distinct visit_table.IP_address)  
FROM country_table
RIGHT JOIN visit_table ON visit_table.id=country_table.id       
GROUP BY country_table.country_name
```